# Remove the nav link corresponding to the current URL

Tags: jquery

I want remove the repeated url in the same page. Please look the following markup.

Page url is http://www.example.com/school-products.html

http://www.example.com/school-products.html is repeated in all widgets. I want to add a class and remove them.

Please help me with that.

I tried with the following jQuery. But it wasn’t working.

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="product-description">
    <h1>School products</h1>
        <p>This is a product description</p>
    </div>

    <div class="aside-right">
        <div class="widget related-products">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/imaging-products.html">Imaging Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/writing-products.html">Writing Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/notebook-products.html">Notebook Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/drawing-products.html">Drawing Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="widget more-products">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/mobile-products.html">Mobile Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/tablet-products.html">Tablet Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computer-products.html">Computer Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/printing-products.html">Printing Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="widget suggested-products">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/home-products.html">Home Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/office-products.html">Office Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/library-products.html">Home Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/toy-products.html">Toy Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.widget li a').each(function () {
        var _remove_repeat = window.location.href;
        if (_remove_repeat === window.location.href) {
            $(this).find(_remove_repeat).addClass('repeat-to-be-removed').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why add a class and then remove the element?

Comment: if you have a different html file for each page, just remove the unwanted links

Comment: You need to explain the issue in more detail. Your comments indicate there's more going on than the original question states.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector to find all list items with anchors pointing to your url and remove them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a[href='/school-products.html']").parent().remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7w6wdjv1/

Comment: Sir, your method will work if I know the url already. This is a random url which can be repeated according to the page. The repeated might be product-1.html or product-2.html or product-3.html etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a `.each` loop. You can simply target any `a` tag matching the `window.location.pathname`, then move up the DOM to it's parent `li` and `remove()` it.

In the example below I've hardcoded a sample path. In production you would need to uncomment the 2nd line to grab the current path.

```js
var currentPath = '/writing-products.html';
// var currentPath = window.location.pathname

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.widget a[href="' + currentPath + '"]').parents('li').remove()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="product-description">
    <h1>School products</h1>
    <p>This is a product description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="aside-right">
    <div class="widget related-products">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/imaging-products.html">Imaging Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/writing-products.html">Writing Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/notebook-products.html">Notebook Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/drawing-products.html">Drawing Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="widget more-products">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/mobile-products.html">Mobile Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/tablet-products.html">Tablet Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/computer-products.html">Computer Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/printing-products.html">Printing Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="widget suggested-products">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/home-products.html">Home Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/office-products.html">Office Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/school-products.html">School Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/library-products.html">Home Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toy-products.html">Toy Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, your method will work if I know the url already. This is a random url which can be repeated according to the page. The repeated might be product-1.html or product-2.html or product-3.html etc.

Comment: You left that part out of the original question. Can you update the question with some example URLs?